# GeoJson : build a Polygon based on Point feature

Tags: polygon, geojson, convex

Dear Stackoverflow team,
I'm impressed that after a bunch of hours digging the forum I still can't find any question/answer similar to my problem :

I have a GeoJson with a lot of Points features. I collect all Points (green in my example, see figure below) that follow some specification (distance between each of them)

Initial Data:
[image: Initial Data]

and I want to link all of them to build a Polygon (which represent an area).

What I'm looking for :
[image: what I'm looking for]

Or Solution accepted :
[image: solution accepted]

So I collect all coordinates from these Points, and to be sure the Polygon follows the GeoJson requirements, I'm using the "rewind" function

```
from geojson_rewind import rewind
```

But at the end, whatever I've tried I only get that kind of Polygon:

[image]

I probably don't use correctly the "rewind" function?

I'm looking for an (easy) automatic way to link all points together in a "convexion hull"

Thanks a lot for any help !

My initial coordinates are collected in a list :

```
[[4.3556672, 50.8538851], [4.3542534, 50.8546955], [4.3567798, 50.8547854], [4.3566527, 50.8541356], [4.3574286, 50.8552813], [4.3572234, 50.8551264], [4.3547752, 50.8545063], [4.3572736, 50.8560176], [4.3571226, 50.8546104]]
```

and the Polygon GeoJson I've managed to build, with the rewind function (recopying the last coordinates to get a Polygon) looks like that :

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              4.357223,
              50.855126
            ],
            [
              4.35678,
              50.854785
            ],
            [
              4.355667,
              50.853885
            ],
            [
              4.356653,
              50.854136
            ],
            [
              4.357123,
              50.85461
            ],
            [
              4.354253,
              50.854695
            ],
            [
              4.354775,
              50.854506
            ],
            [
              4.357429,
              50.855281
            ],
            [
              4.357274,
              50.856018
            ],
            [
              4.357223,
              50.855126
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html) library is very useful for doing these kinds of geometric manipulations.

For generating a polygon of the convex hull of a set of geometries you can use [`object.convex_hull`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.convex_hull):

```py
import shapely.geometry as sg

points = [[4.3556672, 50.8538851], [4.3542534, 50.8546955], [4.3567798, 50.8547854], [4.3566527, 50.8541356], [4.3574286, 50.8552813], [4.3572234, 50.8551264], [4.3547752, 50.8545063], [4.3572736, 50.8560176], [4.3571226, 50.8546104]]
polygon = sg.MultiPoint(points).convex_hull
```

Which results in the following shape:

[image]

Converting it into a GeoJSON with the help of [`shapely.geometry.mapping`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.geometry.mapping):

```py
feature_collection = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {"type": "Feature", "properties": {}, "geometry": sg.mapping(polygon)}
    ],
}

import json
geojson = json.dumps(feature_collection)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, for everything! The accuracy of your answer and the huge help you're bringing :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)